# Paypal sandbox test buyer account not working

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

I created test buyer and test seller account from the paypal sandbox account.
but whenever I try to buy something from my test seller account paypal doesn't verify account and give error stating "Please make sure you have entered your email address correctly."

Is there anything to do apart from creating test buyer account.

I'm using codeigniter's Paypal_Lib.

Comment: Are you also setting your code to use PayPal's sandbox environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this, It was my mistake I did not set $this->paypal_url in library, now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about the codeigniter lib, but:

The test-buyer must be "logged in" to the sandbox-system.
- Log into sandbox, select test-buyer, and click [Enter Sandbod Test Site] - login. STAY
- use the same browser (cookie) to test-buy (I use [Ctrl]n to open a new window)

The test-seller must be the receiver in the buy-form.

The paypal-server in the form must be:
www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
instead of
www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Not super-obvious, but it DOES work, eventually : )
- one of those times when you actually need to read the manual (user-guide)
Depending on what you are doing, the test-users may also need to be verified / busines-accounts..